# word-wrap: break-word on li (list items)?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a menu that looks like the image linked. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCiqJ.jpg).
I thought it would be really simple, but I ran into problems with trying to break the words with CSS only. This is for a cms, so it would be important for the markup to be:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li> etc...
</ul>
```

In case the image link is broken, Im trying to create a menu with no space between words and with words breaking in the middle to accommodate to the width of the `<ul>`

such as:

**HOME***VID
EOS***MUSI
C***CALEND
AR***EVENT
S***PHOTO
S***ABOUT***C
ONTACT*

I faked it here by using manually inputed `<br />` line break tags... is there a way to make this happen with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I know you said you wanted to use an un-ordered list, but I think I've got a solution for you that uses divs and spans instead:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #navigation span:nth-child(even)
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div id="navigation" style="width: 76px; word-wrap: break-word">
    <span>HOME</span><span>VIDEOS</span>
    <span>MUSIC</span><span>CALENDAR</span><span>EVENTS</span>
    <span>PHOTOS</span><span>ABOUT</span><span>CONTACT</span>
</div>
```

I tested this in Chrome only, so your mileage my vary. Nothing in there is browser specific, I don't think, so this should be a workable cross-browser solution.

Comment: yay it works!! now that i think about it... what is the strength of using ul and li for navs? do you know why the UL / LI nav pattern has become so standard? maybe you cant style spans as thoroughly and list items?? any ideas?

Comment: I actually don't know why the practice got started either. I mean nothing is more stylable than divs and spans. Probably back when the internet was young, there was one person who came up with a "cool" nav that was Web 2.0ish and everyone just copied from them.

Comment: lol... probably. I think if i just create a custom template for the nav for my cms it should be fine. thanks for the tip!

Comment: interrreesting......... this only fails when i use li instead of spans and/or nav instead of ul or div!! this is really weird. i dont really know why it happens, but any combination works, even ul and span works fine, but as soon as you put a nav or list item it goes out the window. weird

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `display: inline` on the `<li>` elements.